# setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval is always set to UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum

Tags: ios

I am setting up background jobs to run every 12 hours using the:

```
// NSNumber is actually derived from a config file, but for sake of this example, I initiate it here
NSNumber *interval = [NSNumber numberWithInt:60*60*12]; // 12 hours
[application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:[interval doubleValue]];
```

However, it seems that not matter which value I set in "setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval", the background jobs starts very often, pretty much at the same intervals of UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum (~10-15 min).

Is it possible to set the interval to anything other than UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum/UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalNever ?

Comment: Why are you messing around with NSNumber?  Are you recording your execution time under debugger or in normal operation?

Comment: @Paulw11, as noted, NSNumber is used since I am reading it from a config file as NSNumber (for the sake of this example, I could have used double all along). I am recording my execution time, and it is under 30 seconds.

Comment: But are you running under the debugger or disconnected from Xcode?  Apps will behave differently in the background under the debugger

Comment: disconnected from Xcode. I write all logs to a file so I can read even when phone is disconnected